# Compiling ssh using intel compiler

Tags: ssh, intel, tunnel

Do you think it's possible to compile ssh using the Intel compiler? I don't really know where to start and there's not much info on google, so I thought I'd ask the community.

I really want to take advantage of the compression performance improvements. My idea is to set up an unencrypted ssh tunnel (but with maximum compression) as follows:

`ssh -N -g -f -C -o CompressionLevel=9 -o Cipher=none eamorr@172.16.1.218 -L 6999:172.16.1.218:3129`

Any advice greatly appreciated,

Comment: How do you know that compression speed is a bottleneck in your case ?

Comment: I have a test platform set up. This is for a telecomms use-case with several hundred connections. Compression is an issue for us. We don't want to have to upgrade the quad-core hardware.

Comment: OK - are you planning to use OpenSSH ? I believe it uses zlib for compression.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use OpenSSH...

Comment: OK - build instructions here: http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/openssh.html - when you do the `./configure` steps you'll want to do something like `./configure CC=icc CXX=icpc`.

Comment: @Paul R. Many thanks for that info. Very useful. How can I quickly verify that it's using Intel?

Comment: You'll see the build steps and the compile lines will start with `icc ...` or `icpc ...` rather than `gcc ...` or `g++ ...`.

Comment: OK, cool. Many thanks. I just have to buy the Intel licence now... I'll post back and let you know how I got on.

Comment: You can get a 30 day evaluation license for free first and try it out. If it works out then you can upgrade to the paid version (same compiler, only the license changes).

Comment: I know... My evaluation period has expired... Thanks though.

Comment: Intel are pretty generous with this - they will usually let you have a second evaluation period - worth a try anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build instructions for OpenSSH can be found here: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/openssh.html.

When you do the `./configure` steps you'll want to do something like `./configure CC=icc CXX=icpc` in order to use the ICC compiler rather than gcc.

If you've done it right then when you subsequently do a `make` you should see during the build that the compile lines will start with `icc ...` or `icpc ...` rather than `gcc ...` or `g++ ...`.